# How do I copy the contents in a pointer to a string array to another array?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have included "rawRecipesDevt.h", which is an array containing recipe titles (prefixed with a 0) and these are followed by ingredients (prefixed with a 1). So the first recipe is "Broccoli Coleslaw".
The prefixes should not be printed out and can be stripped off the strings if that is convenient.
The list ends with an empty string as terminator. This is the array below:

```
char *rawRecipes[]={
"0Broccoli Coleslaw",
"1olive oil",
"1white vinegar",
"1broccoli",
"0Creamy Broccoli Salad",
"1broccoli",
"1white sugar",
"1red onion",
"1white wine vinegar",
"0Minnesota Broccoli Salad",
"1eggs",
"1broccoli",
"1red onion",
""
};
```

I want to copy the contents of char *rawRecipes[] to a string array to make printing easier. Should this array be something like char stringsCopied[20][30] (so I don't have to print the 1 or 0) or stringsCopied[20]? I've tried to use strcpy but nothing happens when I try to print. This is what I have so far:

```
#include "rawRecipesDevt.h" //change to rawRecipes.h when submitting
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  int input, i, j, k;
  // char *stringsCopied[250];
  // I am supposed to execute the commands 1-5
  char stringsCopied[250][40];
  printf("\n\n");
  printf("Enter a command by letter \n");
  printf("1. List all Recipes\n");
  printf("2. Print a Recipe \n");
  printf("3. List All Recipes with a given ingredient \n");
  printf("4. List All Ingredients in alphabetical order \n");
  printf("5. Exit the program \n");
  printf("Give input: \n");
  scanf("%d", &input);

  // printf("%s",rawRecipes);
  for (i = 0; i != ""; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j != ""; j++) {
      stringsCopied[i][j] = *rawRecipes[i];
      printf("%s", stringsCopied[i][j]);
    }
  }
  printf("%s", stringsCopied);

  /*if(input==1){
      for(i=0;rawRecipes[i]!='\0';i++){
          if(ingredient(rawRecipes[i]==0)){
              printf("%s\n",&rawRecipes[i]);
          }
      }
  }*/

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself the same question without using the word "string" (use "char", "array of char", "pointer to char", "pointer to array", "array of pointers", ...). The word "string" is *loaded*, does not have a specific objective correspondence to C data structures. *"**pointer to string array**" (in title of your question) ... without context is very hard to determine what this means*

Comment: Indeed, "string" is a loaded term.  On my first reading, my thought is that you already have an array of strings, so your question is a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

To copy a string you should use the [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) function, like e.g.

```
strcpy(stringsCopied[i], rawRecipes[i]);
```

That means you don't need a nested loop to copy character by character (which you don't really do correctly, you only copy the *first* character of `rawRecipes[i]`, i.e. `rawRecipes[i][0]`).

Your loop condition is also wrong, you can't loop until the index becomes an empty string. You need to calculate the number of elements in the source array and loop that amount. You can do that using the `sizeof` operator to get the size of the array and divide it by the size of each element: `sizeof rawRecipes / sizeof rawRecipes[0]`:

```
for(i = 0; i < sizeof rawRecipes / sizeof rawRecipes[0]; ++i)
{
    strcpy(stringsCopied[i], rawRecipes[i]);
}
```